# Need to match string on SQL with '_' ( underscore) value in it

Tags: database, postgresql

Following is an example of a string stored in the DB.

110_112_120_122_130_132_140_143_149_151_154_160_162_165_171_173_194_215_236_257_278_299

Consider this a value for `subjects` field (in the queries below).

I am using the two queries below. I expected each to give a different result, but both give the same output in PostgreSQL.

1 `select * from table_name where subjects like '%_21_%' ;`

2 `select * from table_name where subjects like '%_215_%' ;`

I want to be able to search for either `_21_` or `_215_`. Also, the pattern can be in the beginning (`21_`), middle (`_21_`), or at the end  of the string (`_21`).

Comment: Failing how? The string `_21_` doesn’t appear in your example.

Comment: it is matched with _215_.

Comment: Is this a MySQL or a PostgreSQL problem? What do you mean by "failing"? Are you facing any error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * from table_name where  subjects like '%\_299\_%' 
or subjects like '%299\_%' or 
subjects like '%\_299%';
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does using `CONCAT` escape anything?

Answer (score 2):

`_` is a special character while using `like` and means exect one character, you have to escape it:

```
select * from table_name where   subjects like '%\_21\_%' ;
```

For more information see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Comment: It will not work for **start** and **end** of string to match

Comment: @MayurBendkhale It will work if you use `where concat('_', subjects, '_') like '%\_21\_%'`. The better option would be to not serialize the data in the first place!